# How to change the App ID associated with my (Xcode managed) Team Provisioning Profile

Tags: xcode, ios, provisioning, app-id

I constantly struggle to get my codesigning to work.  I'm trying to get a good generic provisioning profile that will work for all my apps during development.  They're always failing codesign, but they also always install on my phone.  Go figure.

I've created an App ID called `##########.mydomainname.*` and associated it with my development certificate, but when the `Team Provisioning Profile: *` is generated, it uses an App ID that I made when I first signed up over a year ago.  I don't know if this is a problem, but I want to try associating the `Team Provisioning Profile: *` with my `##########.mydomainname.*` App ID.  I'm so sick of constantly fiddling with provisioning - eventually I get it to work, but it's never the same recipe.

Can I somehow edit the App ID used in a profile?

UPDATE:  Marking question as answered, but it looks like the answer is that you can't do what I'm asking.

Comment: I have to wholeheartedly agree with Steve here: Provisioning seems to be some sort of black magic where the recipe changes constantly. And indeed, you can't change the app ID associated with your Team Provisioning Profile. Why? Ask the black magicians at Apple...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't edit exisiting AppID's, but you can associate existing provisioning profile with new AppID or create new one.

Comment: That would be great - can you describe the steps for changing the App ID for the automatically generated `Team Provisioning Profile: *?`  It says it's "Managed by Xcode" and when I click on it, it shows that original App ID, but I see no way to change it.

Comment: You need to log in on [iOS Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles/index.action), click `Edit->Modify` on your provision profile and select preferable AppID from dropdown list.

Comment: That works on any profile that you create yourself, but the `Edit` link is missing for the `Xcode Managed` profile.

Comment: Then you need to create new profile, link it with your application, download it and drop downloaded *mobileprovision file to XCode.

Answer (score 6):

According to **Apple** 
In Apr 2013, it is possible to delete App IDs.
But In Sep 2013, 
Now again they changed so from now impossible to delete App IDs .

**update 19th sept:
But now again you can delete**

Answer (score 2):

After Apple recently added the ability to delete App Ids, I have managed to change the App Id associated with the `Xcode Team Provisioning Profile`.

In my case I had two wildcard App Ids, the one Xcode always used was the first one that I had created in error when I first registered.  To switch to my second preferred wild card id I did the following:

1. In iTunes Connect -> App Ids: Delete the offending App Id.
2. In iTunes Connect -> Provisioning profiles: The Xcode profile is now marked invalid, delete it.
3. In Xcode -> Organiser -> Devices -> Provisioning Profiles: Delete the profile and click refresh.

The new profile was regenerated in iTunes Connect however it wasn't downloaded into the list in Xcode so I downloaded manually from iTunes Connect and dragged it in.

Apparently iTunes connect has some rules about which App Ids can be deleted and Xcode has some default behaviour as to which App Id it chooses so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can only delete App IDs which are not associated with Apps registered with iTunesConnnect.

Comment: HOW? (Instruction is always helpful)

Answer (score 0):

i am using xcode 6.3.2 and the bundle identifier start with yourcompany.yourapp not com.yourcompany.yourapp but when i was creating a certificate it in developer.apple.com it says it should be com.yourcompany.yourapp so that was the reason it was not working.

Then i changed bundle identifier to com.yourcompany.yourapp in xcode 6 to match the provisioning profile and it worked for me.

Hope this helps for some one.